# An exercise regarding complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $K \subset \Bbb C $, convex and $F_K= \{P:P(z)\in K, z\in D(0,1) \}$ where P is a polynomial. If $\hat{P_n}$ is the coefficient of $z^n$ for $P \in F_K$, then $Λ_n = \{ \hat{P_n}: P\in F_K \}$.

Show that $Λ_1=Λ_2=Λ_3=...$

Can you help me? I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a $c \in Λ_1 $ and $n \in \Bbb N$.

There exists a polynomial $P \in F_K$ so that $P(z)=a_kz^k+...+cz+α_0$

For every $z\in D(0,1)$ we know that $z^n \in D(0,1)$.

Therefore if $Q(z)=P(z^n)$ then $Q \in F_K$ and $c=\hat{Q_n}$ and thus $Λ_1 \subset Λ_n$

If $c\inΛ_n$ and $ρ=e^{\frac {2πi}n}$ then for $Q(z)= \frac 1n(P(z)+P(ρz)+P(ρ^2z)+...+P(ρ^{n-1}z))$ we have that $Q \in F_K$ because if $z \in D(0,1)$ then $ρz,...,ρ^{n-1}z \in D(0,1)$ and then $Q(z)$ would be a convex combination of elements of $K$

If $λ\in \{0,1,...,k\}$ then $\hat{Q_λ}= \frac {\hat{P_λ}}n(1+ρ^{2λ}+...ρ^{(n-1)λ})$

If $λ=mn,$ for some $m\in \Bbb N$, then $\hat{Q_λ}=\hat{P_λ}$

If not, then $\hat{Q_λ}=0$

This means that $Q(z)=\hat{P_0}+\hat{P_n}z^n+\hat{P_{2n}}z^{2n}+...+\hat{P_{ln}}z^{ln}=A(z^n)$

For every $z\in D(0,1)$ there exists a $w\in D(0,1)$ so that $w^n=z$

We now have that $A(z)=A(w^n)=Q(w)\in K$ which means that $A\in F_K$ and $c=\hat{P_n}=\hat{A_1}\in Λ_1$ thus $Λ_n \subset Λ_1$